# What does hbm in the NHibernate mapping files stand for?

Tags: nhibernate

When using NHibernate you need to provide some mapping files with the name .hbm.xml which are used to define the mapping from POCO to the database. But what does the hbm stand for? Is it an abbreviation for something or was it created by pure chance?

Comment: a short googling didn't bring the answer. At least not for me.

Comment: probably **h** i **b** ernate **m** apping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate was a spin off from Hibernate a Java application, as dotjoe said

> "h i b ernate m apping"

Cheers